# Is it possible to convert doc file to HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, linux

I am creating a website in which authors can create [EPUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) files. Users will be uploading their books in the `.doc` format. I need to create EPUB file out of that. One single doc file will be having multiple chapters. So I need to parse the `doc` file and split it into chapters. Authors will be using `Heading 1` for their chapter titles.

So in `PHP`, is there any way to parse `doc` files to `HTML` and split it into chapters using `Heading 1`, so that I can create EPUB file.

After some research, I got one [linux app](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/). But I think, it will convert doc to plain text. So I will not be able to split the chapters.

Please suggest me the a solution if you have. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Creating Word, Excel and CSV files with PHP](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php) and [Word with php](http://www.phpdocx.com/)

Comment: @HabenAmare: Thanks. But I need doc to html, not html to doc

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using **[PHPDOCX API](http://www.phpdocx.com/)**.

First try to generate the XHTML from your Word document using [**this**](http://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/format-conversion/generate-xhtml-from-Word-template) function reference

Something like this..

```
require_once '../../classes/TransformDoc.inc';

$document = new TransformDoc();
$document->setStrFile('../files/Text.docx');
$document->generateXHTML();
$document->validatorXHTML();
echo $document->getStrXHTML();
```

After getting the XHTML content you can do various processings like [removing chapter](http://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/docxutilities/remove-chapter-from-Word-document-with-PHP),etc.

Complete documentation can be found **[here](http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/api-documentation)**.

Comment: just want to add that this tool is not free. Moreover, phpdocx convertion functions are avaible from pro+ (~149$)